# Why is this zmq code not working?

Tags: python, zeromq, python-multiprocessing

This test doesn't work.

```
class PrintHandler(MessageHandler):
    def handle_message(self, message):
        print(message)

class FileHandler(MessageHandler):
    def handle_message(self, message):
        with open('nana', 'w') as f:
            f.write(message)


class SubscribeProcess(Process):


    def __init__(self, handler):
        super(SubscribeProcess, self).__init__(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
        self.handler = handler


    def run(self):

        self.address = TcpAddress(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555)
        subscriber = ZmqSubscriber(ZmqBlockingConnection(address=self.address, bind=False))
        subscriber.set_message_handler(self.handler)
        print('............')


class TestZmqSubscriber(TestCase):
    def test_set_message_handler(self):
        address = TcpAddress(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555)
        pub_connection = ZmqBlockingConnection(address, bind=True)
        publisher = ZmqPublisher(pub_connection)
        p = SubscribeProcess(handler=PrintHandler())
        p.start()
        while True:
            publisher.publish('Message number {}'.format(2))
```

I now that's this is not the unit test actually. But I want to see the received messages in console first. Then I will write proper test.

While this two scripts work perfectly.

```
connection = ZmqBlockingConnection(TcpAddress(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555), bind=False)
sub = ZmqSubscriber(connection)
sub.set_message_handler(PrintHandler())
```

---

```
address = TcpAddress(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555)
pub_connection = ZmqBlockingConnection(address, bind=True)
publisher = ZmqPublisher(pub_connection)
while True:
    publisher.publish('Message number {}'.format(2))
```

Inside of subscriber.set_message_handler(handler) is actually this

```
def start_receiving_messages(self, message_handler):
    while True:
        message_handler.handle_message(self.socket.recv())
```

And in debugger I see that the code hangs infinitely in socket.recv()

Maybe I'm using multiprocessing wrong?

EDIT1

```
class ZmqBlockingConnection(Connection):

def start_receiving_messages(self, message_handler):
    while True:
        message_handler.handle_message(self.socket.recv())

def send_message(self, message):
    self.socket.send(message)

def __init__(self, address, bind, hwm=1000):
    self.hwm = hwm
    self.bind = bind
    self.address = address
    self.socket = None

def set_hwm(self, hwm):
    self.socket.set_hwm(hwm)

def configure(self, socket_type):
    self.socket = zmq.Context().socket(socket_type)
    if self.bind:
        self.socket.bind(str(self.address))
    else:
        self.socket.connect(str(self.address))
    self.set_hwm(self.hwm)
```

Comment: You've got the zmq code buried inside your own functions (`ZmqSubscriber`, etc...) so I'm only guessing, but have you subscribed to any topics (or all topics by subscribing to '')? If you don't subscribe to something, you don't get anything.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I've subscribes to all topics.

Comment: @tdelaney Maybe it's not obvious from the question, but the code is unit test and in scripts is basically is the same. The only difference is that in unittest subscriber is started in parallel with publisher with python multiprocessing and in scripts they started in two different processes manually.

Comment: Could you provide a complete script that shows this problem? I'm guessing that the message might be published before the sub is actually connected. This means that the message is long gone (ok a few usecs) before the sub hits recv. Thus, when you call sub.recv it has already missed and the publisher is blocking until 'nothing' receives that first message. Give this section a good read - specifically the slow joiner problem: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out

Comment: @JeffCharter This is the full unittest. Just not all source code. And while the slow joiner could be problem if I would send 1000 messages before subscriber is connected, but as I you can see I'm sending messages in infinite loop. So as soon as sub is connected it should receive something.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was in

```
def configure(self, socket_type):
self.socket = zmq.Context().instance().socket(socket_type)
if self.bind:
    self.socket.bind(str(self.address))
else:
    self.socket.connect(str(self.address))
self.set_hwm(self.hwm)
```

so instead of using singleton I started to create context instances and now it's working.